# Serve TLS certificate dynamically per Django view instead of via nginx/gunicorn

Tags: django, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm using Django's `request.get_host()` in the view code to differentiate between a dynamic number of domains.

For example, if a request comes from `www.domaina.com`, that domain is looked up in a table and content related to it is returned.

I'm running `certbot` programmatically to generate the LetsEncrypt certificate (including acme challenge via Django). I store the cert files as base64 strings in PostgreSQL.

That works perfectly fine, but I can't figure out how to 'apply' the certificate on a dynamic per-domain basis.

I know that this is normally done using TLS termination, nginx or even in gunicorn. But that's not dynamic enough for my use-case.

The same goes for wildcard or SAN certificates (not dynamic enough)

So the question is:

Given I have valid LetsEncrypt certs, can I use them to secure Django views at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django works as a wsgi server. Django gets an http request and does some work of its own. Then it hands it over to middleware and then to your views.
I'm fairly certain that the generic work django does at the start, that it already requires a regular http request, not a "binary blob of unreadable encrypted stuff".
*Perhaps* gunicorn can handle https termination, but I'm not sure.

Normally, nginx or haproxy is used. Also because it is something that needs to be really secure.

I'm using haproxy now, which has a handy feature that you can just point it at a directory full of `*.pem` certificate files and it will read them and use them. So if you could write the certs to such a dir and make sure haproxy is reloaded every time a certificate gets changed, you could be pretty close to a dynamic way of working.